# Is there any difference in below 2 declarations

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

Is there a difference between `int *(a[10])` and `int *a[10]`?

I guess they are the same but, want to get confirmed, as the bracket is confusing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't a difference between those two. The reason that they're the same is because `[]` has higher precedence than `*`, so the brackets are essentially redundant. They're both a declaration for an array of 10 `int` pointers.

There *is* however a difference between the following:

- `int *a[10];`
- `int (*b)[10];`

In this case, `a` is an array of 10 `int` pointers, and `b` is a *pointer to an array* of 10 `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

No difference! MSVC's intellisense function told me.